# Why doesn't the applet run in browser but in IDE?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I've been browsing this site for some time, but this is my first official post.

I'm fairly new to Java (just getting started with applets), and I'm having trouble getting my assigned applet to run in a browser. Everything runs fine in Eclipse, but there is nothing but blank space when I open my .html file.

I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could look over what I have below and offer their expertise. I'm sure I've made some noob mistake and haven't been able to locate it yet. Thanks.

Java source code:

```
// Import necessary classes.
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Eye extends Thread
{
    public static int mouseXcoordinate;
    public static int mouseYcoordinate;
    private static final int EYEWIDTH = 50;
    private static final int EYEHEIGHT = 75;
    private static final int IRISSIZE = 30;
    private static final int PUPILSIZE = 12;
    private Color irisColor;
    private static final int SMALLXRAD = (EYEWIDTH  - IRISSIZE)/2;
    private static final int SMALLYRAD = (EYEHEIGHT - IRISSIZE)/2;
    private int x, y;
    private double newX, newY;
    private Graphics g;

    // Constructor for a new eye.
    public Eye(int x, int y, Graphics g)
    {
        this.g = g;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        // Choose random colors for the iris of the eyes.
        irisColor = new Color((float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random());
    }

    // Draw the eye, in detail.
    private void draw()
    {
        synchronized(g)
        {
            // Erase any old eye color.
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(x - EYEWIDTH/2, y - EYEHEIGHT/2, EYEWIDTH, EYEHEIGHT);
            // Draw the iris and set the color.
            g.setColor(irisColor);
            g.fillOval((int)newX - IRISSIZE/2 + 1, (int)newY - IRISSIZE/2 + 1, IRISSIZE, IRISSIZE);
            // Draw the pupil and set the color.
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval((int)newX - PUPILSIZE/2 + 1, (int)newY - PUPILSIZE/2 + 1, PUPILSIZE, PUPILSIZE);
            // Draw the eye outline.
            g.drawOval(x - EYEWIDTH/2, y - EYEHEIGHT/2, EYEWIDTH, EYEHEIGHT);
        }
    }

    // Continuously calculate the current coordinates and redraw the eyes to follow the coordinates.
    public void run()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            updateCoordinates();
            draw();
            try
            {
                sleep(50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
        }

    }

    // Update the mouse coordinates.
    private void updateCoordinates()
    {

        if (mouseXcoordinate == x)
        {
            newX = mouseXcoordinate;

            if (Math.abs(y - mouseYcoordinate) >= SMALLYRAD)
            {
                if ( (y - mouseYcoordinate) > 0 )
                    newY = y - SMALLYRAD;
                else
                    newY = y + SMALLYRAD;
            }
            else
                newY = mouseYcoordinate;
            return;
        }

        // Find intersection point of line to mouse with eye ellipse
        double slope = (double)(mouseYcoordinate - y) / (double)(mouseXcoordinate - x);
        double numerator = SMALLXRAD * SMALLXRAD * SMALLYRAD * SMALLYRAD;
        double denominator = SMALLYRAD * SMALLYRAD + slope * slope * SMALLXRAD * SMALLXRAD;
        newX = Math.sqrt(numerator / denominator);
        newY = slope * newX;

        // Choose appropriate intersection point
        if (mouseXcoordinate < x)
            newX = -Math.abs(newX);
        else
            newX = Math.abs(newX);

        if (mouseYcoordinate < y)
            newY = -Math.abs(newY);
        else
            newY = Math.abs(newY);

        newX += x;
        newY += y;

        if ( (double)(mouseXcoordinate - x)*(mouseXcoordinate - x) / (SMALLXRAD * SMALLXRAD) + (double)(mouseYcoordinate - y)*(mouseYcoordinate - y) / (SMALLYRAD * SMALLYRAD) < 1 )
        {
            newX = mouseXcoordinate;
            newY = mouseYcoordinate;
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BurleighWatchMe extends Applet
{
    static final int NUM_EYES = 50;
    Eye[] eyes = new Eye[NUM_EYES];
    int count = -1;
    int width, height;

    // Initializes the applet by loading coordinates and starting two eye threads.
    public void init()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionListener()
        {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Eye.mouseXcoordinate = e.getX();
                Eye.mouseYcoordinate = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    // Starts the eye threads.
    public void start()
    {
        if (count == -1)
        {
            width = getSize().width;
            height = getSize().height;
            final Graphics g = getGraphics( );
            eyes[++count] = new Eye(width/4,   height/2, g);
            eyes[count].start();
            eyes[++count] = new Eye(3*width/4, height/2, g);
            eyes[count].start();
        }

    repaint();
    }

    // Redraws a border around the applet.
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(0,0,width-1,height-1);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Watch Me Eyes</title>
</head>
<body>
    Move your mouse pointer over these<br />eyes, and watch them follow it!
    <p />
    <applet code="BurleighWatchMe.class" width="400" height="400">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser? Applets are a dead technology and some current browsers (such as Chrome) have stopped supporting them. Also note that Javascript is nothing to do with Java.

Comment: I've tried it on Chrome, Safari, and changed the user agent on Safari to IE 11, and nothing works. I've heard that the applet tag is almost obsolete in other places. I've tried defining it as an object, and that didn't work either..

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 4) That HTML element implies the code is not in a Jar and not digitally signed. It will not be possible to load it in a modern JRE unless both those things are changed. 5) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Thank you for all of the informative links and help, Andrew. This is a project that was assigned by my teacher, to answer your question.

Comment: Your applet code didn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML code, you've missed out on adding the `codebase` attribute of the `applet` tag. Codebase refers to the directory containing your applet. So **IF THE APPLET IS NOT IN THE SAME DIRECTORY AS THE HTML PAGE** then you have to add the `codebase` attribute inside the `applet` tag. It would take the form below:

```
<applet>
    codebase="E:\Projects\" code="BurleighWatchMe.class" height="400" width="400"
</applet>
```

assuming that the **BurleighWatchMe.class** exists in the directory **E:\Projects**.

However, if the **BurleighWatchMe.class** file exists in the same directory as the **HTML** page and you're still seeing a blank page, then it probably might have been caused because the **JRE** on your system doesn't allow unknown applets. What you have to do is edit the settings to allow local applets. To do that, go to `Start > Configure Java`. Go to the `Security` tab of the Java settings dialog box. In the lower half of the window, you can see a **Site Exception List**. Beside that, there's a button called **Edit Site List...**. Click on that button. You'll see a list of sites whose applets you can run. Click on **Add** to add a new location. In the new field, type `file:///` and press enter,. It'll show you a warning; click on **Continue**. Now click on OK and quit the Configure Java program.

Next, restart the browser. You'll see a dialog box when the applet loads wherein you have to select the **Run** option. You should now be able to run the applet on your browser.

Please note that **Google Chrome** no longer supports applets. The only browsers I know of that support applets are **Firefox** and **Internet Explorer**. I tested it and it worked on these two browsers.

See if it solves your problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You just helped make the difference between an A and a B in my Intro to Java class. Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly was the problem in your case @floyd10325 ?

Comment: It was exactly what you thought it was.. the JRE wasn't allowing unknown applets. Once I edited the security settings, it worked just fine on Firefox.